# OData source for Homebrew?

Tags: feature-request

Possibly a bit of a technical question for most users, but...

I was trying to connect to Homebrew using an OData client but there doesn't seem to be a source listed at http://data.stackexchange.com/ as there are for many other StackExchange sites. Is there one available anywhere or any plans to open one?

Comment: maybe because we're still in beta?